# efficient counting/sorting with lists and csv files

Tags: python, list

I am trying to read a csv file and trying to write logic for printing out in the certain format. I have done it as below and i wish to ask you if I could have done it better. 
My logic below:

```
import csv, urllib2
url = 'http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv'

...
for country in countryList:
    silver = len([item for item in aList if item[7]=='Silver' and item[4]==country])
    gold = len([item for item in aList if item[7]=='Gold' and item[4]==country])
    bronze = len([item for item in aList if item[7]=='Bronze' and item[4]==country])
    result.append((country,gold,silver,bronze))
result
```

Thanks, I Greatly appreciate your advice. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using a Counter.

```
from collections import Counter, namedtuple

...
Result = namedtuple('Result', ['country','medal'])
aList = [Result(country=row[4],medal=row[7]) for row in cr]
medal_counts = Counter(alist)
```

And then sort and print out the results however you desire.

This will give a tally of the occurences of `(country, medal)`, which you should be able to easily parse to give a final list.

Note that you can access a `Counter` as you would a `dict`:

```
swedish_bronze_count = medal_counts[("SWE", "Bronze")]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a list comprehension to append to another list. A list comprehension *produces* a list so you could replace:

`aList =[]
[aList.append(tuple(row)) for row in cr]`

with

`aList = [tuple(row) for row in cr]`

Comment: Yes, thanks timbo. Any comments on the logic for achieving the required output? :)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a data-frame of the results you are looking for

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv')
counts = df.groupby('NOC')['Medal'].value_counts().unstack()
```

Or if you only want to use the standard library:

```
import csv, urllib, io
from collections import defaultdict
url = 'http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv'
webpage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
datareader = csv.DictReader(io.TextIOWrapper(webpage))
counts = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
for line in datareader:
    country = line['NOC']
    medal = line['Medal']
    counts[country][medal] += 1
counts['USA']
```

Outputs

```
defaultdict(int, {'Bronze': 58, 'Gold': 78, 'Silver': 80})
```

And your final desired format

```
res = [(country, v['Gold'], v['Silver'], v['Bronze']) for country,v in counts.items()]
res[0:5]
```

Outputs

```
[('PRK', 0, 1, 1),
 ('GDR', 39, 36, 35),
 ('EST', 4, 1, 1),
 ('AUT', 51, 64, 70),
 ('AUS', 3, 0, 3)]
```

Comment: thanks michael for both the versions..i was trying to not use pandas for this one. For NaN i guess we need to do counts.fillna() before print.